# Java: Create global graphics object

Tags: java, swing, graphics2d

I've extended the JPanel class to draw a graph. The problem that I've got is that I need a global graphics object in order to call it in multiple methods... As an example, here's what I'm trying to do:

```
public class Graph extends JPanel {
  private Graphics2D g2d;

  public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
    g2d = (Graphics2D)g;
  }

  public void drawGridLines(int hor, int vert){
    g2d.someLogicToDrawMyGridLines(someparams);
  }
}
```

This returns a null pointer exception - so my question is: how do I create a global graphics object? What's the best practice in this situation?

Comment: Why do you need a global graphics object? Why can't you call `drawGridLines` from inside `paintComponent` and pass the `Graphics` as a parameter?

Comment: that's what I've got at the moment - but is this a good solution if I'm going to be calling drawGridlines() from another class?

Comment: It's better to pass the `Graphics` object to your helper functions than to try and store a `Graphics` object that might get disposed and no longer be usable.

Comment: ...How would I pass in the graphics object externally?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My suggestion would be this:

```
public class Graph extends JPanel {
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
        drawGridLines(g2d, ......);
    }

    private void drawGridLines(Graphics2D g2d, int hor, int vert){
        g2d.someLogicToDrawMyGridLines(someparams);
    }
}
```

i.e. keep all the uses of your graphics context inside the `paintComponent` call.

Comment: +1 for factoring; the corresponding approach in [tag:jfreechart] may be seen among the various `drawXxx()` methods in the implementations of [`AbstractRenderer`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/renderer/AbstractRenderer.html).

Answer (score 5):

> How would I pass in the graphics object externally?

Don't. The graphics context is only valid during the invocation of `paintComponent()`. Instead, use the [MVC pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model-view-controller), discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3072979/230513), to update a model that notifies any listening view to render itself. [`JFreeChart`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jfreechart/info) is a complete example.